# Where can I order a replacement screen for a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm selling my MacBook but I want to replace the screen first so that I can sell it as like new.

The rear of the screen (the side with the Apple logo) has some chips.

Where can I order a replacement screen for a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014), or is there a reputable UK company that I can send it to to have it done?

Comment: How bad are the "chips" and does the display function properly?  I ask because, can you get that much and more, then the cost for replacing it when selling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place that I have sourced replacement/upgrade parts for my Apple products has been [Amazon](http://radnex.us/mbp_15-inch_2013-2014-Retina-Display). A quick search for your part resulted in a number of good sources.

I have used eBay in the past and more often than not there were severe quality/customer service issues.  Buying through Amazon, has been much more efficient and customer service focused.

Given that Amazon has sites in the US and the EU (including UK after Brexit) you should have no problem sourcing through them.

The repair itself isn't very difficult if you have some basic experience.  [ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro_15%22_Retina_Display_Mid_2014) has an excellent tutorial.  You won't need to remove the logic board (thankfully) but you will need to disconnect some components, especially the battery.

For this particular model, you will need a [pentalobe screwdriver](http://radnex.us/pentalobe_screwdriver) as Apple stopped using the standard Philips screws.

Comment: Thanks. Have you ever replaced a screen? Just wondering on the skill level required.

Comment: Many times.  It's not that "hard" it's just that it's just that you have to be careful and pay attention to where all the different screws go.  I posted a link to ifixt document that details how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would very strongly recommend against that. You will never, ever get your money back. It's a 2014 MacBook. That's no age for the screen. But if it is replaced, it is not "as new", it is a 2014 MacBook with a screen that was repaired. *I* wouldn't want a MacBook where the screen is repaired, I'd rather have the original screen, with nobody messing around with the innards of the MacBook, causing god knows what damage. That's what any potential buyer would think.